# Google Sheets - onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run two onEdit on the same sheet but only one works at a time:

First function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if ([8,9].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(new Date());
}
}
```

Second function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var value = (typeof e.value == "object" ? e.range.getValue() : e.value);
if (e.range.columnStart == 14 && value == "ISSUED") {
e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
}
}
```

I am an entry level when it comes to performing script, any assistance? Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

you have two options. here is example of hybryd code:

### nested:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  moveRowsFromSheetToSheet_(e);
}

function moveRowsFromSheetToSheet_(e) {
  // start of code
  if(condition == met) {
    //operation to follow
  } //closes if statement operations; no close to moveRowsFromSheetToSheet_()

  function moveRowsFromSheetToSheet1_() {
    //start of code
    if(condition == met){   
      //operation to follow
    } //closes if statement operation
  } //closes moveRowsFromSheetToSheet1_()
  moveRowsFromSheetToSheet1_; //calls moveRowsFromSheetToSheet1_() so that it will run after moveRowsFromSheetToSheet_() code
} // closes moveRowsFromSheetToSheet_()
```

### unnested:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  moveRowsFromSheetToSheet_(e);
  moveRowsFromSheetToSheet1_();
}

function moveRowsFromSheetToSheet_(e) {
  // start of code
  if(condition == met) {
    //operation to follow
  } //closes if statement operations


function moveRowsFromSheetToSheet1_() {
  //start of code
  if(condition == met){   
    //operation to follow
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; based in your comment, I would just combine my two functions into one single script? Sorry, I’m not familiar with unnested or nested but I will read up on it. Would you be able to guide me and use my formulas as example and demonstrate what it would look like when combined? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach in your case is to use your current functions and wrap them around a single `onEdit` trigger as you can only have one per project:

```
function onEdit(e){
  myFunction1(e);
  myFunction2(e);
}

function myFunction1(e) {
if ([8,9].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(new Date());
}
}

function myFunction2(e) {
var value = (typeof e.value == "object" ? e.range.getValue() : e.value);
if (e.range.columnStart == 14 && value == "ISSUED") {
e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
}
}
```

Just save the code and it will work upon edits.